# WCF Multiple Http/Https Endpoints problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WCF Service multiple endpoint configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425256/wcf-service-multiple-endpoint-configuration)

I have a WCF service:

```
https://myservice/service.svc
https://myservice/service.svc?wsdl
```

Given below are the related sections of my WCF Application's web.config (let me know if you need more):

```
<bindings>
 <basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="basicHttp">
  <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
    <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
  </security>
  </binding>
 </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
 <serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="MyService.ServiceBehavior">
  <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
  <serviceCredentials>
    <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="MembershipProvider" membershipProviderName="SqlMembershipProvider"/>
  </serviceCredentials>
  <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentInstances="100" maxConcurrentSessions="100"></serviceThrottling>
  </behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<services>
 <service behaviorConfiguration="MyService.ServiceBehavior" name="MyService.Service">
  <endpoint address="/ClientA" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp" name="basicHttpEndpoint" contract="MyService.IService"></endpoint>
  <endpoint address="/ClientB" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp" name="basicHttpEndpoint" contract="MyService.IService"></endpoint>
  <endpoint address="/ClientC" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp" name="basicHttpEndpoint" contract="MyService.IService"></endpoint>
  <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
 </service>
</services>
```

I want my clients to be able to access the service through the following links, but the links don't work: (or maybe my syntax is wrong for the links below, let me know if that is the case)

```
https://myservice/service.svc/ClientA
https://myservice/service.svc/ClientB
https://myservice/service.svc/ClientC
```

The following links work, but I don't think this is due to my configuration, as if i write anything after the last forward slash it still works ....

```
https://myservice/service.svc?wsdl/ClientA
https://myservice/service.svc?wsdl/ClientB
https://myservice/service.svc?wsdl/ClientC

https://myservice/service.svc?wsdl/asfgvafgfgf ... (this works too !!!)
```

Please let me know how to achieve this. I don't want to create separate service for all clients.

Comment: am sorry, but am really stuck with this, i need some answer, my thread question was left answered in the sea of questions, so asked it again, if you can delete the last one (or if you can tell me the way to do it) .. i'll behappy to delet that one .... but please let this live ... i need some way out ...

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the '/' off of the endpoint addresses (just like the mex endpoint address).  The address assumes relative pathing.

On my machine in a sample app, the url looks like...

```
http://localhost:56988/Service1.svc?ClientA
```

Comment: did that, dosent work either .... tell me one thing, if remove the '/' to test if it worked what shall i type in the browser ... https://myservice/service.svc/ClientA ??? i tried that, it didn't work !!!

Comment: try http://localhost:56988/Service1.svc?vaifhebvifuvb it will still work ...